# Deploy CodeCommit code to EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I just started using AWS CodeCommit and my workflow looks like this:

1. Develop on laptop with local git repo
2. Push changes to CodeCommit remote repo
3. Run deploy script on EC2 instance that executes `git clone`

Is there a way to automatically run step 3 using Lambda/CodeDeploy/CodePipeline?  The documentation suggests more complex use cases than the one I have.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what languages you're working with? If it's a SPA for example, it will only need CodeBuild -> S3. If it's a compiled language, you might need CodeBuild as well.

Comment: You might consider running the command using system manager as part of the build stage in pipeline where you can have two stage source and build in pipeline